# Using a foreach loop, how do I get all records to be placed below eachother?

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I'm gathering information from a database, and want to place the gathered data below each other. The code I'm running now is:

```
@foreach ($drivers as $driver)
    <table>
        <tr> <?= $driver->name;?> </tr>
        <tr> <?= $driver->age;?> </tr>
        <tr> <?= $driver->country;?> </tr>
        <tr> <?= $driver->team;?> </tr>
        <tr> <?= $driver->number;?></tr>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

This places the 5 pieces of info besides each other and goes to the next line when it's done with one driver. This is not really what I want to do because this causes a lot of tables, but if I put the foreach inside the table, it just prints out one line of results. How do I alter my code, so that I get the following result:

- Name
- Age
- Country
- Team
- Number
- Name
- Age
- etc. etc.

And then preferably with whitespace added between new drivers.
Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: If you have never heard that tables do not consist of _rows_ only, but that those rows consist of _cells_ ... then you should perhaps be learning some HTML basics, before you start playing with PHP.

Comment: As a side note, since it seems you're using Laravel Blade, you can use its own syntax for echoing variables, and change `<tr> <?= $driver->name;?> </tr>` to `<tr> {{ $driver->name }} </tr>` which also deals with escaping HTML entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You HTML markup is wrong. You need to have a `<td></td>` tad in each `<tr></tr>` tag like so

The `<tr></tr>` means "a row in a table" while the `<td></td>` means "a column in a row"

so you need to have multiple columns (`td`) in each row (`tr`)

```
<table>
    @foreach ($drivers as $driver)
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <?= $driver->name;?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?= $driver->age;?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?= $driver->country;?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?= $driver->team;?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?= $driver->number;?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will cause invalid html, how is this:

```
<table> <!-- start table outside foreach -->
  @foreach ($drivers as $driver)

  <tr>  <!-- do each row inside foreach -->
    <td>
      <?= $driver->name;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $driver->age;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $driver->country;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $driver->team;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $driver->number;?>
    </td>
  </tr>

  @endforeach
</table>
```

This will result in one table with each driver on their own row

Answer (score 1):

**`Try with below.`**

```
<table>
   @foreach ($drivers as $driver)
    <tr> 
         <td> <?= $driver->name;?> </td>
         <td> <?= $driver->age;?> </td>
         <td> <?= $driver->country;?> </td>
         <td> <?= $driver->team;?> </td>
        <td> <?= $driver->number;?></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont want a table for each data set you are getting. TD's are for table data and TR's are for table rows

```
<table>
    @foreach ($drivers as $driver)
       <tr> 
           <td><?= $driver->name;?></td>
           <td><?= $driver->country;?></td>
           <td><?= $driver->team;?></td>
           <td><?= $driver->number;?></td>
       </tr> 
    @endforeach      
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove   and use the double curly brackets instead

```
<table>
   @foreach ($drivers as $driver)
    <tr> 
         <td> {{ $driver->name }} </td>
         <td> {{ $driver->age }} </td>
         <td> {{ $driver->country }} </td>
         <td> {{ $driver->team }} </td>
        <td> {{ $driver->number }} </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```